# Upload document to Sharepoint 2013 Online using webservices

Tags: development, 2013, web-services

I have a client who is implementing customer portals in Sharepoint 2013 Online. The current program distributes documents to the customers by mail. Now we have to upload the documents to the customer portal.

I try to use the copy webservice in sharepoint. I created a test project and added the webservice as Web Reference and wrote the following testcode:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string baseUrl = "https://mycustomer.sharepoint.com/sites/";
    string customer = "customerportalname";
    string serviceUrl = "/_vti_bin/copy.asmx";
    string destinationDirectory = "/folder/";
    string fileName = "uploaded.xml";

    string username = "username@outlook.com";
    string password = "password";

    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.LoadXml("<fiets><onderdeel>voorwiel</onderdeel><onderdeel>achterwiel</onderdeel><onderdeel>trappers</onderdeel><onderdeel>stuur</onderdeel><onderdeel>frame</onderdeel></fiets>");

    byte[] xmlByteArray;
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        xmlDocument.Save(memoryStream);
        xmlByteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    string destinationUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", baseUrl, customer, destinationDirectory, fileName);
    string[] destinationUrlArray = new string[] { destinationUrl };

    FieldInformation fieldInfo = new FieldInformation();
    FieldInformation[] fields = { fieldInfo };


    CopyResult[] resultsArray;

    using (Copy copyService = new Copy())
    {
        copyService.PreAuthenticate = true;
        copyService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        copyService.Url = string.Format("{0}{1}", baseUrl, serviceUrl);

        copyService.Timeout = 600000;

        uint documentId = copyService.CopyIntoItems(destinationUrl , destinationUrlArray, fields, xmlByteArray, out resultsArray);
    }
}
```

When I execute the code I recieve the following error:

```
The request failed with the error message:
--
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/_forms/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_vti_bin%2fcopy.asmx">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
--
```

It looks like I'm not authenticated and get redirected. The credentials however are correct. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

To be able to connect to SharePoint 2013 Online you have to attach the Office 365 authentication cookies as explained in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2011/05/14/part-2-headless-authentication-with-sharepoint-online-and-the-client-side-object-model.aspx) post.
My problem however is that there is also an ADFS involved. How can I autheticate against the ADFS?

Comment: It is an Sharepoint 2013 Online implentation that came with the Office 365 license. We have no control in that way, so I cannot determine if there is a ISA server or not.

Answer (score 1):

This error most probably occurs due to incorrect authentication mode.
Since SharePoint Online (SPO) uses *claims-based authentication*,  [NetworkCredential Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can not be utilized for authentication in SPO.

One of option to perform the authentication against the ADFS in SPO, would be to  utilize  [SharePointOnlineCredentials class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx) (part of [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)).

### How to authenticate SharePoint Web Services in SharePoint Online (SPO) using SharePointOnlineCredentials class

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve authentication cookies:

```
private static CookieContainer GetAuthCookies(Uri webUri, string userName, string password)
{
    var securePassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (var c in password) { securePassword.AppendChar(c); }
    var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
    var authCookie = credentials.GetAuthenticationCookie(webUri);
    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    cookieContainer.SetCookies(webUri, authCookie);
    return cookieContainer;
}
```

### Example

```
string sourceUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Documents/SharePoint User Guide.docx";
string destinationUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Documents/SharePoint User Guide 2013.docx";
FieldInformation[] fieldInfos;
CopyResult[] result;
byte[] fileContent;
using(var proxyCopy = new Copy())
{
     proxyCopy.Url = webUri + "/_vti_bin/Copy.asmx";
     proxyCopy.CookieContainer = GetAuthCookies(webUri, userName, password);

     proxyCopy.GetItem(sourceUrl,out fieldInfos,out fileContent);
     proxyCopy.CopyIntoItems(sourceUrl,new []{ destinationUrl}, fieldInfos, fileContent, out result);
 }
```

### References

- [Remote Authentication in SharePoint Online Using Claims-Based
  Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147177.aspx)
- [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

Answer (score 0):

At least on error is here

```
copyService.Url = string.Format("{0}{1}", baseUrl, serviceUrl);
```

this will create the string: `https://mycustomer.sharepoint.com/sites//_vti_bin/copy.asmx`
which is not a valid URL (notice the double "//", and also it does not point to a web but just to the managed path of sites)

Comment: The client has a test site defined. Using the following URL results in the same error: https://mycustomer.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_vti_bin/copy.asmx. In the browser the url works.